# Use a docker secret to login to docker registry inside container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-in-docker

I have a docker secret `docker-artifactor-cred` available as a secret in the kubernetes ecosystem. It is created using the below config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: docker-artifactor-cred
  namespace: kube-system
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: <encoded_config>
```

In one of the pods I want to use this secret to login to the docker artifactory using the `docker login` command inside the container. The container uses a `docker-in-docker` image so I need to login to docker registry from a shell script running inside the container.

I can mount this secret in the pod's container but how can I best make use out of it to login to artifactory?

As it is not a username-password based secret, I cannot just use the username/password from it using `envFrom` secret. I can (may be) take the `data.dockerconfigjson` from the secret, decode it to create a config file, save it in `~/.docker` and have it used but I dont want to keep this file on the container like this. What would be a better way to use it in `docker login`?

Comment: Did you follow K8s documentation on [pulling images from private registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)?

Comment: @p10l I did follow this doc and that is how I created the secret. I do not want to pull image for running a container, but pull image from inside a running container (my container is a docker-in-docker type of container)

Answer (score 0):

`docker login` creates *config.json* anyawys.

Simple solution would be to create a Kubernetes secret with username and password, or using *config.json* file with `--from-file` option, and mounting secret as file inside a pod

```yaml
...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/root/.docker"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: my-secret
...
```

You could also try using secrets management tools like [HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/), but it's probably more hassle then it's worth.

Comment: this does not work out of the box, you need to add key to the volume. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56363168/4653423. I found it today when trying your suggestion.

But that does not work either if you plan to connect to multiple repositories (in my case I had to connect to AWS ECR as well) as the mounted path is a read-only one. You need to take care of having the config file writable to add auth for other repository